# How to approach a long time process in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, ftp, cron

I am working on a PHP product application, which will be deployed on several client servers (say 500+). What my client's requirement is, when a new feature released in this product, we need to push all the changes ( files & db ) to clients server using FTP/SFTP. I am a bit concerned about transferring files using FTP to 500+ server at a time. I am not sure how handle this kind of situation. I have came up with some ideas, like

- When user (product admin) click update, we send an ajax request, which will update first 10 servers, and returns with the remaining count of servers. From the ajax response, we will send again for next 10, and so on.

OR

- Create a cron, which runs every 1 mins, which check whether any update is active, and update the first 10 active servers. Once it complete the transfer for a server, it changes the status for that server to 0.

I just want know, is there any other method to do these kind of tasks ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the whole code to a code repository mechanism like `Git` and then push all over present files to the created repository. Go to any one server and write a cron for auto pull the repository to the severs and upload that cron to every server.

In future if you like to add new feature just pull the whole repository and add the feature. Push the code again to repository it will be pulled by cron automatically in all the server where you kept the cron previously.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to provide some suggestions and insight into your suggested methods:

1. In both the methods, you'll have to keep a list of all the servers where your application has been deployed and have keep track whether the update has been applied to a particular one or not. That can be difficult if in future you want to scale from 500+ to say 50,000+.
2. You are also not considering the case, where the target server might not be functioning at the time you send the request for update.

I suggest, instead of sending the update from your end to target server, you achieve the same in the opposite direction. As you said, you are developing an entire PHP Application to be deployed on Client Server, I suggest you develop an **Update Module** into it. The Target Server can send a request to your servers at designated time to check whether there is any Update available or not. If there is, then I suggest following two ways to proceed further

1. You send an update list, providing the names and paths of files to be updated, along with any DB changes, the same can be processed on Client Side accordingly.
2. You can just send a response saying there is an update available, then a separate process launches on Client Server which will download all the files and DB changes from the Server.

For maintaining concurrency of updates you can implement a Token System, or can rely on the Time-stamp at which the update happened.